The purpose of requiring splitting homomorphism for a section to get a split sequence
I see this from Dummit Foute and want to check my understanding: Now pick any $c \in C$,we can get a corresponding representaive $\bar{\beta} \in B/ker \phi$ and we specify it as one possible $\beta \in B$. If we can the make the collection of such $\beta$ (denoted by $S$) a group then we find an isomorphic copy of $C$ in $B$.The purpose of forcing $\mu$ to be homomorphism is to ensure if both $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2 \in S$ then $ \beta_1 + \beta_2 \in S$. Now we can say $S$ gives a complement to the isomorphic copy of $A$ in $B$.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.
